# python: how do I reload shared object loaded with numpy.ctypeslib

Tags: python, numpy, shared-libraries, ctypes

I load a `.so`, written in `C`, in `Python` using the following:

```
import numpy.ctypeslib as npct
from ctypes import c_int
libcd=npct.load_library('name_so', 'some/path')
libcd.namefunction.restype=None
libcd.namefunction.argtype=[c_int]
```

I am changing the source code of the `.so` and recompiling it.
how do I reload the `so` without exiting and reopening python?

Comment: Call `_ctypes.dlclose(libcd._handle)` (POSIX) or `_ctypes.FreeLibrary(libcd._handle)` (Windows) until it raises an exception because the library is no longer loaded. Make sure you delete all references to the existing `libcd`, because using them after the library is unloaded will crash Python.